# aws lambda: docker container support & efs mount at the same time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

lambda + docker support is very useful. Now I want to add aws efs to the mix, as of today, is this doable? (even with some sleight of hand that would require tweaking the docker image)

the idea is to leverage the docker support for OS purposes and efs to load/save stuff.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors have you encountered?

Comment: I am playing around in the AWS management console but I cannot seem to make it work. I can do it with either one or the other. not both. perhaps I am doing something wrong config wise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this same problem and it turned out to be I had to add the NFS TCP port 2049 to my security group.  My Lambdas were unable to communicate at the network level.  The error I was getting was

```
Execution failed due to configuration error: The function couldn't connect to the Amazon EFS file system with access point arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:us-east-1
```

Hopefully someone finds this useful.

Comment: it is! thank you!